# How do I select row with maximum value of some column

Tags: sql, timesten

Hi this seems like very easy task but I could not find answer for it. I would like to get only one row from table where some specific column has maximum value.

So, for example if I have this table:

```
╔═══════╦═════╦═══════╗
║ Name  ║ Age ║ Color ║
╠═══════╬═════╬═══════╣
║ Jakub ║  55 ║ Red   ║
║ Nick  ║  24 ║ Black ║
║ Alice ║  38 ║ Blue  ║
╚═══════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

I would like to know how can I get the row "Jakub 55 Red" based on that the age is maximal.

I though it will be something like `select * from people where age is max` but it doesn't work. I am using TimesTen.

Comment: `Select top 1 * from table order by Age desc` - or `limit 1`, depending on specific syntax needed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.NAME,S.AGE,S.COLOR
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS S
WHERE S.AGE=(SELECT MAX(AGE) FROM YOUR_TABLE)
```

Could you please try this one

Comment: Thanks, this would probably work, but @Stu 's answer was what I was looking for `select first 1 * from people order by age desc`

Comment: Yes.That solution is better. If it is supported in your TimesTen then it would be the best choice

Answer (score 0):

Based on Stu's answer the solution I was looking for is `select first 1 * from people order by age desc`, thank you all for help!